# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration . I am not using maven and my integration-spring.xml is located inside src/resources/integration-spring.xml and all my jars are having v4.0.5+. I am getting below exception when running my JUnit Test case.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [resources/integration-spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
```

integration-spring.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

<int:gateway service-interface="com.fil.MyService" id="myGateway"
    default-request-channel="in" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="in" method="someMethod"
    ref="exampleHandler" />

<bean id="exampleHandler" class="com.fil.MyServiceImpl" />
```

Test.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import com.fil.MyService;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/resources/integration-spring.xml" })
public class MyServiceTest {

@Autowired
private MyService service; 

@Test
public void test() {
    try{
        service.single("hELLO ");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: hmm no class def error might suggest that you are loading two different versions of the `MessageConverter` class or you dont invoke the JUNIT test properly, (are you adding the *jars as external resources?). If you could switch to maven , instead of manually making the lib dir

Comment: I have added my Test class as well. @AntJavaDev

Answer (score 2):

This problem may occur, when you use not compatible spring boot and spring libraries too.
I my case I had to to update spring boot to current version.

Answer (score 1):

You really should use maven or gradle to manage your project's dependencies; doing it manually is just too painful - especially with regard to getting all the versions right.

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/converter/MessageConverter

The `org.springframework.messaging` package is provided by the `spring-messaging` jar file from the core Spring Framework. It contains general messaging abstractions used by Spring Integration (and other Spring projects).

Since you are "new" to the framework(s), you really should be using the latest versions:

```
org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.3.9.RELEASE
```

which depends on

```
org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.3.8.RELEASE
```

by default.

> v4.0.5+

You **must** make sure that all jars from the same project (Spring Integration or Spring Framework) have their same respective versions (`spring-beans`, `spring-messaging`, etc must match and `spring-integration-*` must all be the same version).