# Spring 3 and org.springframework.messaging

Tags: java, spring, maven

I maintain a system that uses Spring 3.1.2-RELEASE, and this cannot change. I added code to test the JMS endpoints, but it will not run because of missing class `org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageHandlerMethodFactory`. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631770/spring-amqp-has-noclassdeffounderror-in-springframework-retrycallback-class) that the `org.springframework.messaging` package is distributed in the `spring-messaging` artifact. However, this does not appear to exist in Spring 3, only Spring 4 and later. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828663/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-messaging-converter-messagec/43832254#43832254) that I must keep versions consistent.

So then where can I get this package for Spring 3.1.2-RELEASE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, things get messy when you mix Spring versions.

> So then where can I get this package for Spring 3.1.2-RELEASE?

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but you may need to find an alternative means of testing. According to the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/MessageHandlerMethodFactory.html), MessageHandlerMethodFactory wasn't introduced until Spring 4.1.  Looking at the [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging), the Spring messaging module wansn't available until 4.0.

Comment: I think you're right. The activemq-all library that I'm using to test is what is calling the missing file. It probably isn't fully compatible with Spring 3.